# How to assert that function throws with a specific error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-assert

I'm using Node v18 ( with the built-in testrunner) and the package [`assert/strict`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) to test that a function call throws an error with a custom error message.

I think my code should look like

```
assert.throws(() => myFunction(), 'content of error.message goes here');
```

Unfortunately I get the following error

> error: 'The "error/message" argument is ambiguous. The error message "content of error.message goes here" is identical to the message.'

[image]

I also tried

```
assert.throws(
  () => myFunction(), 
  error => {
    assert.ok(error instanceof CustomError);
    assert.strictEqual(error.message, 'content of error.message goes here');

    return true;
  });
```

and

```
assert.throws(myFunction, 'content of error.message goes here');
```

but unfortunately that didn't help. This might be a duplicate of [node assert: Test error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473259/node-assert-test-error-message) but I don't want to pass in regular expressions because there is no need for it.

Does someone know how to fix the assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertthrowsfn-error-message), it looks like you can pass an object (and should for the OP case)...

```
// tests whether the thrown error has a particular message
assert.throws(myFunction, { message: 'content of error.message goes here'});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#strict-assertion-mode

> error cannot be a string. If a string is provided as the second argument, then error is assumed to be omitted and the string will be used for message instead. This can lead to easy-to-miss mistakes. Using the same message as the thrown error message is going to result in an ERR_AMBIGUOUS_ARGUMENT error. Please read the example below carefully if using a string as the second argument gets considered:

and

```js
function throwingSecond() {
  throw new Error('Second');
}
```

> If it was intended to match for the error message do this instead:
> It does not throw because the error messages match.

```js
assert.throws(throwingSecond, /Second$/);
```